# Firebase data in BigQuery, what is "stream_id"?

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have some tables of Firebase event data in BigQuery, and one of the many (poorly documented) columns is "stream_id". Does anyone know what this column represents and what it can be used for? Does it represent a unique session?

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, the stream_id is pretty much used to map data to a combination of package name + platform so that you can, for example, separate Android events from iOS events. Anyhow, you will not be able to use it to represent a unique session.

If you want to work with sessions, have a look at **ga_session_id**.

> Unique session identifier (based on the timestamp of the session_start event) associated with each event that occurs within a session

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately "ga_session_id" doesn't exist in data from Firebase.

Comment: It should be there, I myself use it. See this post for some ideas on how to use it. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/12/new-changes-sessions-user-engagement.html

Comment: Use it in BigQuery? I just tried to compose an SQL query with it and get `Unrecognized name: ga_session_id at [2:3]`

Comment: Yes, in BigQuery.

Comment: #standardSQL
SELECT event_name, params.value.int_value
FROM `xyz`,
UNNEST(event_params) AS params
WHERE params.key = 'ga_session_id'
LIMIT 100

Comment: you're right, it's an event parameter. Strangely it only appears in the basic events like "screen_view", but not our own custom events.

Comment: Thank you Vesper. I got "ga_session_id"  (Firebase).